# Can't resize images in css since i'm working with xampp and php documents

Tags: html, css, class

HTML:

```
<div id="shoppingcart">
    <img src="assets/images/cart.png" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS:

`` #shoppingcart img { width: 16%; height: 16%; }` ``

I tried everything I know from creating classes, other id's, divs and changing the code to width or max-width. I just don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: It's doubtful that xampp or php is causing you your problem.  Neither should prevent you from resizing your image.

Comment: Make sure not to forget the css link in the header of your HTML file.

Comment: That's 16% of the *defined* `height` and `width` of the `#shoppingcart` div, are you aware of that? (i.e. the *defined* bit)

Answer (score 0):

Can you better explain the problem you are having? Code works fine.

```css
#shoppingcart img{
width:16%;
height:20vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="shoppingcart">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: There is no better explanation I don't know. It worked fine like this with html but since I'm using php it's weird